# Delphi: one thread cannot see other thread's array

Tags: multithreading, arrays, delphi, access-violation

**ANSWER:
Allright, that was quite simple (probably I made this mistake coz I need more sleep :) ):
I've created First Thread and it created Sub-Threads and FREE-ed it-self. So it was naturall that some sub-thread souldn't access not existing memory (before they tryed - First Thread wasn`t already in memory).**

Hi,
I'm trying to make simple application.
My needs are to create for example 1-3 threads (I will call them First Threads), which will create next few threads (I will call them Sub-Threads).

I know how to do it, this is what I have done:

First Thread definition:

```
 type
 TFirstThread = class(TThread)
   // 
   strict private
     fID:cardinal; //fID = position on watki array + 1
     fDoneItems:cardinal;
     fItems:TSomeRecordAr;     

     //(...)
     procedure ParseItem(var item: TSomeRecord; itemID:cardinal);
   private
   public                 
   published                            
     function GetItem(itemindex:cardinal):TSomeRecord;  
     procedure SetItem(itemindex: cardinal; item: TSomeRecord);                             
     //(...)
     procedure Execute; override;
 end;
```

TSomeRecord is:

```
TSomeRecord = record
  str,str2:string;
  lst:TStrings;
  continue:boolean;
end;
```

Sub-Thread definition:

```
TSubThread = class(TThread)
  public
    fReady:boolean;
    fID,fItemID:cardinal;
    procedure Execute; override;
end;
```

And also array of First Threads:

```
watki:array of TFirstThread;
```

Body of First Threads:

```
{ TFirstThread }

//(...)

procedure TFirstThread.ParseItem(var item:TSomeRecord; itemID:cardinal);
begin
     //(...)
     with TSubThread.Create(False) do begin
       fID:=Self.fID;
       fItemID:=itemID;
       fReady:=True;
     end;
end;

procedure TFirstThread.Execute;
var
  i:cardinal;
begin
FreeOnTerminate:=True;
while fReady=False do
  Sleep(10);

//(...)
fDoneItems := 1;

for i := 0 to High(fItems) do begin
 ParseItem(fItems[i], i);
end;
// 
end;

function TFirstThread.GetItem(itemindex: cardinal): TSomeRecord;
begin
 result:=fItems[itemindex];
end;

procedure TFirstThread.SetItem(itemindex: cardinal; item: TSomeRecord);
begin
 fItems[itemindex]:=item;
end;
```

Body of Sub-Threads:

```
procedure TSubThread.Execute;
var
ftd:string;
tries:cardinal;
fItem:TSomeRecord;
begin
FreeOnTerminate:=True;
while fReady=False do
Sleep(10);
try
  //(...)
   fItem := watki[fID-1].GetItem(fItemID); //HERE AV << 
   fItem.continue:=True;
  //(...)
finally
watki[fID-1].SetItem(fItemID, fItem);
//(...)
//Free;
end;
end;
```

This is how doeas it looks in practice:
While I'm testing, I'm creating just 1 First Thread and start it. It has 3 items, so it creates 3 Sub-Threads.

When I make breakpoint in TFirstThread this is what I can see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGaBO.jpg

everything is OK,
but after that when I make breakpoint in TSubThread this is what i get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXhHW.jpg

so everithing is OK except fItems - idk why, but I can't see it's content. So ofc I get AV, coz item I want to get doesn't exist.

Why can it be like that? Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Btw I'm using Delphi 2009

**ANSWER:
Allright, that was quite simple (probably I made this mistake coz I need more sleep :) ):
I've created First Thread and it created Sub-Threads and FREE-ed it-self. So it was naturall that some sub-thread souldn't access not existing memory (before they tryed - First Thread wasn`t already in memory).**

Comment: This code smells quite strongly. You aren't using real synchronisation objects. You are using Sleep. I think there is a very good chance that there as more bugs lurking.

Comment: @David - meaby it looks strangly, but I'm already using techniques (in places where are \\(...) ) that will help me "synchronize" my objects. So as longest as this is working I'm OK with it :)

Comment: @David - but thanks for Your advice, I'll for sure consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, that was quite simple (probably I made this mistake coz I need more sleep :) ): I've created First Thread and it created Sub-Threads and FREE-ed it-self. So it was naturall that some sub-thread souldn't access not existing memory (before they tryed - First Thread wasn`t already in memory).